# Technique for distorting part of an image to take features from another image?

Tags: image-manipulation

I have a project of a community website, where people can alter/manipulate photos that they upload, in a particular way.  For example, a person could select various contours and control points on their nose, and do the same for an image of another person's face, and hence morph their own photo so that it distorts the nose to match that of someone else's.

The setting up of a profile based site, where images can be uploaded, is under the belt, but I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction for image manipulation.

I have been searching for scripts/libraries - chiefly php and python but gotten nowhere.

I tried searching composite picture scripts, but what I found just stuck one picture onto another. Like cutting and pasting one nose onto another picture, without blending it in. I tried searching morphing scripts, but I just found scripts that turned one image into another image. I tried searching for image superposition, but that just gave composite image script.

Neither of the above are what I am trying to do.

What is the technique for distorting part of an image to take features from another image?

Comment: Did you try what's described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071063/is-there-a-library-for-image-warping-image-morphing-for-python-with-controlled

Comment: [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) has C, C++ and Python bindings.